# Using Haskell's Req library with Scalpel to save files to client

Tags: haskell

I am 99% of the way there on a Haskell / Scalpel scraper to pull down thousands of .gz files in batches and store them locally on my client.

I am trying to now take the chunked `[[String]]`s and get them into IO so they can be saved.

I am using `import Network.HTTP.Req`.

```
-- This is the argument for the downloadFiles function
chunkLinks :: IO [[String]]
chunkLinks = fmap (chunksOf 10) filterNonGz

-- THIS IS WHAT YOU EXECUTE 
downloadFile :: (MonadHttp m) => String -> m ()
downloadFile url = do
    -- Pull them into memory
    contents <- req GET (https (T.pack url)) NoReqBody bsResponse mempty

    -- Get the filename itself
    let fileName = head $ reverse $ T.splitOn "/" (T.pack url)

    -- Write them to the client (the filename will be the url)
    liftIO $ BSS.writeFile (dataDir ++ (T.unpack fileName)) (responseBody contents)


dataDir = "./Data/LODES/"

eatChunks :: (MonadHttp m) =>  m [()]
eatChunks = do
    (wtf :: [[String]]) <- liftIO $ (take (5) <$> chunkLinks)
    fmap concat $ liftIO $ mapM (liftIO . mapConcurrently (liftIO . downloadFile)) wtf
```

I am getting an error on `downloadFile` in the last line.

The error is:

```
• Could not deduce (MonadHttp IO)
    arising from a use of ‘downloadFile’
  from the context: MonadHttp m
    bound by the type signature for:
               eatChunks :: forall (m :: * -> *). MonadHttp m => m [()]
    at /private/var/folders/70/kchtzk4j0hs398f95ywd78x00000gn/T/ghc-mod39229/UsCensusDataLodesScraper39228-2281.hs:195:1-37
```

Please excuse the `liftIO`s littered about.  They are desperate attempts to get this to work...

Does anyone know what to do next?

For reference, the output of `chunkLinks` looks like this:

```
[["https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2002.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2003.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2004.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2005.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2006.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2007.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2008.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2009.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2010.csv.gz","https://lehd.ces.census.gov/data/lodes/LODES7/ak/od/ak_od_aux_JT00_2011.csv.gz"], ...etc.
```

Comment: The only instance of `MonadHttp` is `Req`. The way to run a `Req` action is `runReq`. So instead of trying to use `liftIO` to raise your `downloadFile` from `IO` to something, which can't work because `downloadFile` isn't an `IO` action, use `runReq` to lower your `downloadFile` from something to `IO`.

Comment: I tried this, but clearly I am still doing something wrong: `fmap concat $ mapM (mapConcurrently (runReq downloadFile)) wtf`

Comment: Trying to use defaultHttpConfig: `fmap concat $ mapM (mapConcurrently (runReq . (defaultHttpConfig downloadFile))) wtf`